# jQuery-ui: Differences between local and remote inclusion of stylesheet

Tags: css, jquery-ui

When I include a jquery-ui stylesheet for a resizable jquery-ui dialog remotely like so

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.18/themes/start/jquery-ui.css" />
```

I get this result:

[image]

but when I download the very same file and include it locally like so

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./jquery-ui.css" />
```

I get this result:

[image]

Note the missing resize handle in the lower right corner which seems to be the only difference.

What causes the difference?

Comment: Looks like the button also has a gradient...I think you just need to go to : **/jquery-ui.css** and make sure the bg paths are path correctly

Comment: You are missing the image file located in the folder. Use http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/ and download the class. Make sure to add ALL FILES.

Comment: guess my answer didnt win :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jquery-ui references a bunch of image sprite sheets. When including the reference from ajax.googleapis.com the path to the image resolves properly because google hosts those images on their server and has them in the proper location. However in your local copy of the jquery-ui.css i'm guessing there's a good chance your images are not in the proper location.

I'm using jquery ui in a current project and my folder structure is:

```
Content
  images            <--- this is the jquery ui sprite iamges folder
  jquery-ui.css
```

Answer (score 0):

go to **/jquery-ui.css** and make sure the bg paths are path correctly